# Named templates in jTemplate?

Tags: jtemplate

Is there any way to have multiple templates, and tell jTemplate which one to use? All examples I've seen always start with a template called `MAIN`.

I would like to put this into one template file:

```
  {#template MAIN1}
    ...
  {#/template MAIN1}

  {#template MAIN2}
    ...
  {#/template MAIN2}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass parameters when calling template, pass some variables as parameters by using setParam method. By using $P.param_name, we can check the parameter value inside template and can include template based on the parameter.

Comment: So, the answer seems to be "No" - there can only be one "Main" template.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://jtemplates.tpython.com/

Click on the "MultiTemplates" link under Documentation.

example:

*** main template *** (all part outside templates are invisible}
{#template MAIN}

{$T.name.bold()}
  {#include table root=$T.table}

{#/template MAIN}

---

*** main table ***
{#template table}

{#foreach $T as r}
  {#include row root=$T.r}
  {#/for}

{#/template table}

---

*** for each row ***
{#template row}
 
  {$T.name.bold()}
  {$T.age}
  {$T.mail.link('mailto:'+$T.mail)}
 
{#/template row}

Comment: Thanks for the response... I was aware of this, but was wanting to have 2 MAIN templates in one file.  From what I can tell, that is not possible.